# Why is my .feature file saying "Undefined step reference", although my cucumber tests run fine and detect the steps?

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, feature-file

Intellij is saying my step is undefined when I'm looking at the .feature file.

[Intellij undefined step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqSaj.png)

But the cucumber .feature file runs fine, and it is definitely matching on the step.

My TestNG runner code:

```
package package1;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

@CucumberOptions(plugin = "pretty", features = "src/test/resources/package1", glue = "package1")
public class Runner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }

}
```

The step in the feature file:

```
Feature: test feature
  Scenario: test feature scenario
  Given there has been a pebkac
```

My step in the StepDefinitions file:

```
Given("there has been a pebkac", () -> {
            //driver.findElement(By.id("editTextFieldId")).sendKeys("test");
            autoTools.getElement(new String[]{"editTextFieldId", "IOSIDHERE"}, AutomationTools.IdType.DEFAULT, 15).sendKeys("test");
            System.out.format("test: %n\n");

            //throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
        });
```

Why is intellij complaining that it can't find this step? I tried using the step definition file with annotations instead and ran into the same issue.

I notice though that if I go to the feature file and right click -> add step, it will add a step using a deprecated Given method. This makes me feel like I may be using the wrong dependencies, though I got them from the cucumber tutorial on their website.

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:4.7.4'

    compile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.14.3'
    compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-testng', version: '4.7.4'
    compile group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '7.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intellij was out of date, updating it resolved this problem.

Reference: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/40044